# Convergent sequence and accumulation point

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove that Given a convergent sequence Sn of real numbers that takes infinitely many distinct values, the set *S*={ $S_n$, n$\in$$\Bbb N$} has exctly one accumulation point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $s,s_1$ are two distinct accumulation points, where $s$ is the limit of the sequence and $s \neq s_1$ then, take $r = |s-s_1|/2$, because $S_n \rightarrow s$, there is some $N$ such that for $n \geq N$, $|s_n - s| < r$, but this means that  there is no element of $S$ at distance less than $r$ from $s_1$, contradicting it being an accumulation point.